# How to save spaCy model onto cache?

Tags: python, caching, spacy

I'm using spaCy with Python for Named Entity Recognition, but the script requires the model to be loaded on every run and takes about 1.6GB memory to load it.
But 1.6GB is not dispensable for every run.
How do I load it into the cache or temporary memory so as to enable the script to run faster?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you, if you only do NER, you can install the parser without vectors.
This is possible giving the argument **parser** to:

`python -m spacy.en.download parser`

This will prevent the **700MB+** Glove vectors to be downloaded, slimming the memory needed for a single run.

Then, well, it depends on your application/usage you make of the library.

If you call it often it will be better to pass `spacy.load('en')` to a module/class variable loaded at the **beginning** of your stack.

This will slow down a bit your boot time, but spacy will be ready (in memory) to be called.

(If the boot time is a big problem, you can do **lazy loading**).